# Can you forward packets from TUN to router on a Mac?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables

I'm intercepting packets on a toy packet sniffer I have that just pulls all traffic off a `TUN` device. I've setup a default route to the TUN on my mac via:

```sh
sudo route -n add default 10.1.0.10
```

where `10.1.0.10` is the IP of the `utun5` device. While I can see the packets coming through to my program, I want to just print them then forward them off to the router. For example, if I were to `curl google.com` or `ping yahoo.com` I would see the packet, but the client would still get the expected response as normal.

I feel like on Linux, this isn't too hard with IP forwarding, NAT and of course, `iptables` via iproute2. On Mac, I just can't crack how this is supposed to work. Any help or reading is appreciated.

From the coding side, I'm using Go and the `water` library for simplifying the creation of the tun device.

Here is a basic implementation:

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/songgao/water"
    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {
    ifce, err := water.New(water.Config{
        DeviceType: water.TUN,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("Interface Name: %s\n", ifce.Name())

    packet := make([]byte, 2000)

    // Replace "en0" with your internet-facing network interface name
    internetInterface, err := net.InterfaceByName("en0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenPacket("ip4:4", "0.0.0.0") // Listen for IPv4 packets
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    rawConn, err := ipv4.NewRawConn(conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {
        n, err := ifce.Read(packet)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        header, err := ipv4.ParseHeader(packet[:n])
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error parsing IPv4 header: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        cm := &ipv4.ControlMessage{
            IfIndex: internetInterface.Index,
        }

        err = rawConn.WriteTo(header, packet[header.Len:n], cm)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error writing packet to raw socket: %v", err)
        }
    }
}
```